# PreparedStatement slower than Statement with JDBC

Tags: postgresql, select, jdbc, prepared-statement, benchmarking

I am currently working on weather monitoring.
For example a record of temperature has a date and a location (coordinates).
All of the coordinates are already in the database, what I need to add is time and the value of the temperature. Values and metadata are in a CSV file.
Basically what I'm doing is:

1. Get time through the file's name
2. Insert time into DB, and keep the primary key
3. Reading file, get the value and coordinates
4. Select query to get the id of the coordinates
5. Insert weather value with foreign keys (time and coordinates)

The issue is that the

"SELECT id FROM location WHERE latitude = ... AND longitude = ..."

is too slow. I have got 230k files and currently one file takes more than 2 minutes to be processed... Edit: by changing the index, it now takes 25 seconds and is still too slow. Moreover, the PreparedStatement is also still slower and I cannot figure out why.

```java
private static void putFileIntoDB(String variableName, ArrayList<String[]> matrix, File file, PreparedStatement prepWeather, PreparedStatement prepLoc, PreparedStatement prepTime, Connection conn){
    try {

        int col = matrix.size();
        int row = matrix.get(0).length;

        String ts = getTimestamp(file);
        Time time = getTime(ts);

        // INSERT INTO takes 14ms
        prepTime.setInt(1, time.year);
        prepTime.setInt(2, time.month);
        prepTime.setInt(3, time.day);
        prepTime.setInt(4, time.hour);
        ResultSet rs = prepTime.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        int id_time = rs.getInt(1);


        //for each column (longitude)
        for(int i = 1 ; i < col ; ++i){

            // for each row (latitude)
            for(int j = 1 ; j < row ; ++j){

                try {
                    String lon = matrix.get(i)[0];
                    String lat = matrix.get(0)[j];
                    String var = matrix.get(i)[j];
                    lat = lat.substring(1, lat.length()-1);
                    lon = lon.substring(1, lon.length()-1);
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lon);
                    double value = Double.parseDouble(var);

                    // With this prepared statement, instruction needs 16ms to be executed
                    prepLoc.setDouble(1, latitude);
                    prepLoc.setDouble(2, longitude);
                    ResultSet rsLoc = prepLoc.executeQuery();
                    rsLoc.next();
                    int id_loc = rsLoc.getInt(1);

                    // Whereas this block takes 1ms
                    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rsLoc = stm.executeQuery("SELECT id from location WHERE latitude = " + latitude + " AND longitude =" + longitude + ";" );
                    rsLoc.next();
                    int id_loc = rsLoc.getInt(1);


                    // INSERT INTO takes 1ms
                    prepWeather.setObject(1, id_time);
                    prepWeather.setObject(2, id_loc);
                    prepWeather.setObject(3, value);
                    prepWeather.execute();

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ECMWFHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ECMWFHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);        
    }

}
```

What I already did:

- Set two B-tree index on table *location* on columns latitude and longitude
- Drop foreign keys constraints

PreparedStatements in parameters are :

```java
        // Prepare selection for weather_radar foreign key
        PreparedStatement prepLoc = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id from location WHERE latitude = ? AND longitude = ?;");

        PreparedStatement prepTime = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO time(dataSetID, year, month, day, hour) " +
                "VALUES(" + dataSetID +", ?, ? , ?, ?)" +
                        " RETURNING id;");            

        // PrepareStatement for weather_radar table
        PreparedStatement prepWeather = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO weather_radar(dataSetID, id_1, id_2, " + variableName + ")"
                            + "VALUES(" + dataSetID + ", ?, ?, ?)");
```

Any idea to get things go quicker?

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bits
- 15.5 Gio
- Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- PostgreSQL 9.5.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
- Netbeans IDE 8.2
- JDK 1.8
- postgresql-42.2.0.jar

Comment: Just trying to be helpfull. Are you sure your index is being hit ? What is its definition ? Are you sure there is no miss because of precision concerns (i.e. the latitude inside the DB are not exactly the same as the ones you read from the file, therefore the index is useless) ? Would it be reasonnable to cache locations ? Would it be reasonnable to index e.g. a string concatenating lon/lat up to a fixed precision (non unique index, but far lesser cardinality) ?

Comment: Actually I don't know if it's being hit, how could I do to know that? What do you mean by its definition? It's just a b-tree on the primary key. No issues with precision, the DB was feed with those files. For the last two questions, I am not sure to understand what you mean. The "location" table has 21594 rows in it (122 lat and 177 long).

Comment: Show your table and index definition, use `auto_explain` to capture the execution plan form Java in the PostgreSQL log, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on the statement. With all this information, we should be able to say more.

Comment: Hello Issou. Just a totally off topic comment: have you considered using PostGIS `geometry` for storing the coordinates? I know that having coordinates as numbers seems straightforward, but it is very limited. PostGIS has more than 1k really kickass out of the box functions that will make your life A LOT easier in the future, specially if you want to publish this data using a WFS (Web Feature Service). Peace! :-)

Comment: @Issou putting an index on the primary key will (obviously ?) have zero impact on the performance of queries that have no predicate on the primary key (e.g. it will speed up `WHERE ID = X` but have no impact on `WHERE lat=X and lon=Y`).

Comment: @GPI Thank you! I added two index on both latitude and longitude. It takes now 1ms to execute the query. However it doesn't change anything for the PreparedStatement, which still takes around 14ms to be executed...

Comment: You should add a single index on latitude **and** longitude, that is more efficient.

Comment: @Issou : you should measure which of the statement is slow. If it is querying statements, I suggest caching (no need to make a SQL request if there are like 10000 different locations, juste load them all in a HashMap). If it is writing, I suggest you take a look at JDBC batching.

Comment: @GPI Thanks a lot. Using HashMap and batched queries solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. The key issue you have here is you miss `ResultSet.close()` and `Statement.close()` kind of calls.
2. As you resolve that (add relevant close calls) you might find that having SINGLE `con.prepareStatement` call (before both for loops) would improve the performance even further (of course, you will not need to close the statement in a loop, however you still would need to close resultsets in a loop).
3. Then you might apply batch SQL

Answer (score 0):

Using [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html), the point where query becomes latent could be figured out.

One of the situation where I have encountered case alike being:

- Compound queries e.g. parameterized *similar* date ranges, from different tables and then joining them on some indexed value. Even if the date in the above serve as index still the query produced in preparedStatement, could not hit the indexes and ended up doing a scan over the joining data.